# How to use gsub in awk to find and replace ("./") and (".txt") characters within a file

Tags: regex, unix, awk, gsub

I want to remove characters "**./**" and "**.txt**" from my file using sub and awk

This is what my input looks in file

```
./file_name.txt|1230
```

I want the output to be

```
  file_name|1230
```

So far This is what I have written.I will use  the output of this gsub and pass it to awk and print it.Rest of my code is working except this .

```
gsub ( "[./txt]","" )
```

Comment: `"./"` isn't a character, it's a string. Ditto for `".txt"`. Bracket expressions like `[...]` are for characters.

Comment: @ Ed Morton -Thanks.Instead of the square bracket should I be using round () ?

Comment: See @JamesBrown's answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `gsub` instead and remember to escape `.` and `/` like `\.` and `\/`:

```
$ echo "./file_name.txt|1230" | awk '{gsub(/\.\/|\.txt/,"")}1'
file_name|1230
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you said you need to replace in a file you can use,

```
awk '{gsub(/\.txt|\.\//, "")}1'  file_name > tmp && mv tmp file_name
```

or you can use `gawk` which is much simpler,

```
gawk -i inplace '{gsub(/\.txt|\.\//, "")}1' file_name
```

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63891/what-is-the-meaning-of-1-at-the-end-of-awk-script) explains what `1` at the end of the statements means.

Comment: downvoter, please explain why have i been down-voted? if it was about escaping `.` and `/`, I have fixed it.

Comment: Helpful the link with the explanation of what `1` means. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

You mention `awk` and the other answer has answered it but here's a way you can do this with `sed`:

```
sed 's|\./||g; s|\.txt||g' <<< "./file_name.txt|1230"
```